# Reusable UITableViewCells change after I scroll

Tags: ios

For a split second before my `UITableviewCell` with a picture updates it shows the picture of the reused cell. Does anyone know the best practice to deal with that?

I have tried the following (but might have implemented wrong):

1. `prepareForReuse`. I tried removing the picture but the old image still appears briefly it still flickers (I can rewrite the code and post if someone thinks I missimplimented and it should have worked)
2. I tried several ways of caching the images: still not fast enough
3. Not reuse cell: not an option for many reasons

Code of the image load:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        // Configure the cell...
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        UIImageView *pictureImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:8];
        //Using AFNetworking
        [pictureImageView setImageWithURL:pictureURL];


        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: how large is the image? Do you load images asynchronously and only than update the cell?

Comment: They are large in terms of geometric size so it's very visible but they are only about 40kb each. They load asynchronously only when the cell load the first time after which they are cached. Using AFNetworking.

Comment: Can you show some code ?

Comment: Perhaps you could nil the image (or set to background color) in:  tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: You are a genius sir!! Put it as an answer so I can give you a check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is not to try to change the image as the cell appears but rather to hide the old image as the cell disappears before it's reused. There is a method to do that:

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(BigPictureCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   UIImageView *pictureImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:8];
   pictureImageView.image = nil;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to replace this line :

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

by this one :

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

and this one :

```
pictureImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithColor:O_BACKGROUND_COLOR];
```

by this one :

```
pictureImageView.image = nil;
```

because creating an `UIImage` from a color consume more than just remove the image.

And you mustn't try to remove your image in `prepareForReuse` since it's explicitly said in the documentation that no Layout operations should be done in this function.

**EDIT**

There is something wrong in your code here :

```
UIImageView *pictureImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:8];
```

It's really weird since you declare your `UITableViewCell` previously if nil with :

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell...
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

So there is really no way to be sure your `UITableViewCell` will have a `UIImageView` with tag 8.
So if not here, you should have other code about that, and it could (certainly must) be the origin of your problem.

Comment: Just tried this and it still shows for a split second. This is so frustrating because it shouldn't but I still briefly see the image of the other cell.

Comment: It makes no difference. You are right that I do not need the `if (cell == nil)` line because I use an identifier from storyboard but I do not think thats the cause of the problem.